# Sencha Touch itemtap

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have a list of contacts that sencha touch is displaying in a list. Then when you click a name in the list it should slide to the right and say Hello {contact name}! but when it slides over right now it just says Hello !on line 29 is where the action is happening for item tap i belive the problem is here. I just dont know how to format it correctly. Below is my source code.

```
ListDemo = new Ext.Application({
name: "ListDemo",

launch: function() {

    ListDemo.detailPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'detailpanel',
        tpl: 'Hello, {firstName}!',
        dockedItems: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                items: [{
                    text: 'back',
                    ui: 'back',
                    handler: function() {
                        ListDemo.Viewport.setActiveItem('disclosurelist', {type:'slide', direction:'right'});
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    });

    ListDemo.listPanel = new Ext.List({
        id: 'disclosurelist',
        store: ListDemo.ListStore,
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} {lastName}</div>',

        listeners:{
            itemtap: function(record, index){               
            ListDemo.detailPanel.update(record.data);
            ListDemo.Viewport.setActiveItem('detailpanel');
            }
        }
    });

    ListDemo.Viewport = new Ext.Panel ({
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'card',
        cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
        items: [ListDemo.listPanel, ListDemo.detailPanel]
    });

}
```

});

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first argument passed to the itemtap event isn't the record of the List item tapped, it's the DataView itself.

From the docs:

> itemtap : ( Ext.DataView this, Number index, Ext.Element item,
>   Ext.EventObject e ) 
>       Fires when a node is tapped on
>
> ```
> Listeners will be called with the following arguments:
> this : Ext.DataView
>     The DataView object
> index : Number
>     The index of the item that was tapped
> item : Ext.Element
>     The item element
> e : Ext.EventObject
>     The event object
> ```

You can grab the tapped record by using:

```
dataView.store.getAt(index); // where 'dataView' is 1st argument and 'index' the 2nd
```

Comment: I'm just learning sencha touch what is the dataview object, the index of the item that was tapped, the item element, and the event object. Also, how is dataView the 1st argument and 'index' the 2nd. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A List inherits from a DataView and the 'itemtap' event is one that is inherited from the DataView base class. The documentation therefore is a little confusing when using a List. The first argument of the event handler contains a reference to your List instance (equivalent to the variable 'ListDemo.listPanel' in your example). The 'index' argument refers to the place in the List the tapped item falls e.g. 1st list item tapped gives index = 0, second item tapped gives index = 1 etc. For simple use cases you can ignore the item and e arguments - plus i'm running out of space.. :)

Answer (score 9):

```
itemtap: function(view, index, item, e) {
    var rec = view.getStore().getAt(index);
    ListDemo.detailPanel.update(rec.data);
}
```

That's how I got it to work.

Comment: Note that in Sencha Touch 2 the update method is now setData()