# Clickable List items in Sencha

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha touch. I have a list-search example. Now I want to make each of my list item clickable. i.e Clicking on which it should go to a details page. I have posted the .js file I am using. Please let me know the changes that has to be made to make the list items clickable.

```
Ext.application({
//setup the startup screens and icon for mobile devices
tabletStartupScreen: 'resources/images/tablet_startup.png',
phoneStartupScreen : 'resources/images/phone_startup.png',
icon: 'resources/images/icon.png',
glossOnIcon: false,

// require any components we are using in this example
requires: [
    'Ext.data.Store',
    'Ext.List',
    'Ext.field.Search',
    'Ext.Toolbar'
],

/**
 * The launch method is called when the browser is ready, and the application can launch.
 *
 * Inside our launch method we create the list and show in in the viewport. We get the lists configuration
 * using the getListConfiguration method which we defined below.
 *
 * If the user is not on a phone, we wrap the list inside a panel which is centered on the page.
 */
launch: function() {
    //get the configuration of the list
    var listConfiguration = this.getListConfiguration();

    //check if the device is a phone
    if (!Ext.os.is.Phone) {
        //add a panel into the viewport
        Ext.Viewport.add({
            //panel gets special styling when it is floating
            xtype: 'panel',

            //give it a fixed width and height
            width: 380,
            height: 420,

            //center the panel
            centered: true,

            //modal gives it a mask
            modal: true,

            //disable the hide on mask tap functionality of modal
            hideOnMaskTap: false,

            //give it a fit layout so the list item stretches to the size of this panel
            layout: 'fit',

            //give it 1 item which is the listConfiguration
            items: [listConfiguration]
        }).show();
    } else {
        //add the list into the viewport
        Ext.Viewport.add(listConfiguration);
    }
},

/**
 * Returns the configuration of the list for this example, to be inserted into the viewport in the launch method.
 */
getListConfiguration: function() {
    return {
        //give it an xtype of list
        xtype: 'list',

        ui: 'round',

        pinHeaders: false,

        //itemTpl defines the template for each item in the list
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div>',

        //give it a link to the store instance
        store: this.getStore(),


        grouped: true,
        emptyText: '<div style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: center">No Matching Items</div>',
        disableSelection: true,

        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',

                items: [
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                    {
                        xtype: 'searchfield',
                        placeHolder: 'Search...',
                        listeners: {
                            scope: this,
                            clearicontap: this.onSearchClearIconTap,
                            keyup: this.onSearchKeyUp
                        }
                    },
                    { xtype: 'spacer' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
},

/**
 * Returns a new store instance if one hasn't been created yet
 * @return {Ext.data.Store}
 */
getStore: function() {
    //check if a store has already been set
    if (!this.store) {
        //if not, create one
        this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            //define the stores fields
            fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],

            //sort the store using the lastname field
            sorters: 'lastName',

            //group the store using the lastName field
          groupField: 'lastName',
          //  groupField: '',

            //and give it some data
            data: [
                { firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz' },
                { firstName: 'Rupesh',   lastName: 'Kumar' },
                { firstName: 'Rupesh',   lastName: 'Kumar' },
                { firstName: 'Akshatha',   lastName: 'Shetty' },
                { firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan' },
                { firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Avins' },
                { firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins' },
                { firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Dougan' },
                { firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias' },
                { firstName: 'Jacky',   lastName: 'Ngyuyen' },
                { firstName: 'Jay',   lastName: 'Ngyuyen' },
                { firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson' },
                { firstName: 'Rob',   lastName: 'Avins' },
                { firstName: 'Ed',     lastName: 'Dougan' },
                { firstName: 'Jamie',    lastName: 'Poulden' },
                { firstName: 'Dave',      lastName: 'Spencer' },
                { firstName: 'Abraham',   lastName: 'Avins' },
                { firstName: 'Jacky',   lastName: 'Avins' },
                { firstName: 'Rob',    lastName: 'Kaneda' },
                { firstName: 'Ed', lastName: 'Elias' },
                { firstName: 'Tommy',    lastName: 'Dougan' },
                { firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Robinson' }
            ]
        });
    }

    //return the store instance
    return this.store;
},

/**
 * Called when the search field has a keyup event.
 *
 * This will filter the store based on the fields content.
 */
onSearchKeyUp: function(field) {
    //get the store and the value of the field
    var value = field.getValue(),
        store = this.getStore();

    //first clear any current filters on thes tore
    store.clearFilter();

    //check if a value is set first, as if it isnt we dont have to do anything
    if (value) {
        //the user could have entered spaces, so we must split them so we can loop through them all
        var searches = value.split(' '),
            regexps = [],
            i;

        //loop them all
        for (i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
            //if it is nothing, continue
            if (!searches[i]) continue;

            //if found, create a new regular expression which is case insenstive
            regexps.push(new RegExp(searches[i], 'i'));
        }

        //now filter the store by passing a method
        //the passed method will be called for each record in the store
        store.filter(function(record) {
            var matched = [];

            //loop through each of the regular expressions
            for (i = 0; i < regexps.length; i++) {
                var search = regexps[i],
                    didMatch = record.get('firstName').match(search) || record.get('lastName').match(search);

                //if it matched the first or last name, push it into the matches array
                matched.push(didMatch);
            }

            //if nothing was found, return false (dont so in the store)
            if (regexps.length > 1 && matched.indexOf(false) != -1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                //else true true (show in the store)
                return matched[0];
            }
        });
    }
},

/**
 * Called when the user taps on the clear icon in the search field.
 * It simply removes the filter form the store
 */
onSearchClearIconTap: function() {
    //call the clearFilter method on the store instance
    this.getStore().clearFilter();
}
});
```

Thanks in adv.

Comment: You know you're supposed to accept an answer when one of them answers your question ? If none of them does, then maybe you should provide more information about your problem.

Comment: pls assist me in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596404/need-help-in-sencah-touch-2-search-list thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at the `listeners` config for the list component.

With this config, you can add a listener for the `itemtap` event

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-itemtap

You can find some help for the code here:

[Sencha Touch itemtap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318382/sencha-touch-itemtap)

Hope it helps